# How to move database to another shard in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have one shard(1 primary, 3 secondary replica set) and many database inside. I want to move one database to my own shard. Without downtime. Is there an easy way to do this? Using mongodb tools.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by your "own shard"? Another cluster?

Comment: @yaoxing yes, it is. I need to somehow get away to my environment and not depend on anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1: Leverage Replica Set

If the purpose is to migrate that specific database to a new cluster, since you have only one shard, you can simply add a replica set member to that cluster. Then on a certain point you may want to:

1. remove the member from original cluster;
2. use it to create a new cluster;
3. switch your application to the new cluster;
4. reserver only database you want. remove other ones;

Pros:

1. using replication is probably the most robust way to clone data.
2. And it's simple to do.

Cons:

1. Got some down time, but with proper preparation down time can be within minutes.
2. Replication clones all data of original cluster, not only the one you wanted. You may remove other databases later.

### Solution 2: Change Stream

If you are using MongoDB >= 3.6, you can use MongoDB [change stream](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/changeStreams/) to get changed data in realtime, and apply them in new cluster. This way you need to do some coding.

### Solution 3: MongoConnector

https://github.com/yougov/mongo-connector